Why does the partial derivative of $y'$ with respect to $y$ vanish?
I'm following Weinstock's Calculus of Variations.
On page 25 it says:

We have in this case
$$f=\frac{d g}{d x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}y',$$
so that the Euler-Lagrange equation (25) reads
$$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y \partial x} + \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}y'-\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \right) = 0.$$

I'm assuming that when taking the partial derivative of the second summand with respect to $y$, we should use the multiplication rule, so the part that contains the derivative of $y'$ vanishes somehow. I get that $y'$ doesn't explicitly depend on $y$, but it depends on $x$ in general and you can write $x$ as a function of $y$(provided $y(x)$ is bijective).
I might not have paid enough attention to calculus. Why are partial derivatives weird in this way? Do we only care about what we define the function to explicitly depend on?
I just want a good intuitive picture of why it is this way.

It isn't the partial derivatives that get weird, it's the whole concept of total derivative (like $dg/dt$) when a physicist is insufficiently explicit about arity and dependencies of a "physical quantity" (hah!)
However, you have omitted an important piece of context and I had to look it up in Winestock myself. In this case $f$ is a function of 3 variables that takes a special form involving the partial derivatives of a function $g$ of only 2 variables:
$$f(w_1,w_2,w_3)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(w_1,w_2)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_2}(w_1,w_2).w_3$$
In other words, the role of the third variable $w_3$ is just independent from $g$ or $w_1$ or $w_2.$
When writing the Euler-Lagrange equation for this particular $f$ the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the third variable (confusingly called $y'$) is just the factor in front of $w_3.$
While the function $x\mapsto y'(x)$ is completely determined by the function $x\mapsto y(x),$ the value of either of those two functions does not appear as an argument to the other one.

What I'm confused by is that $y'$ in general related to $y$. And I still don't have a clear enough picture of why $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} (\frac{\partial g(x, y) }{\partial y} y')$ is not expanded using the multiplication rule. I do understand that we treat $y'$  as independent from $y$ somehow, but how can that be justified if the form of $y$ defines what $y'$ is?

The point is that, in the Euler-Langrange equation, $f$ is considered as a function of 3 independent variables, deliberately ignoring the fact that $y'$ has any relationship with $y.$ That independence becomes muddled if we use the same symbols for functions and variables. When a physicist writes a partial derivative with respect to $y,$ she really means a partial derivative with respect to the second variable, evaluated at a point where the second variable is itself the value of a function called $y(x).$

I see that we're deliberately ignoring the dependance of $y'$ on $y$, but I do not see why this is justified

Oh, wait. So is $y'$ like a numerical value of the derivative? Is that what's meant?

Yes, I think that's a fair description. The function $x\mapsto y'(x)$ is of course completely determined by the function $x\mapsto y(x)$ but the value of $y(x)$ does not appear as a variable where the function $y'$ is evaluated.

Yeah, I think I've got a good picture now. Thanks for your guidance

The equation that you provided is not the correct one.
Comparing with Weinstock (page 25), the actual equation is instead
$$
\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y \partial x}+ \frac{\partial^2g}{\partial^2 y} y'  - \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}) = 0
$$
Hope this clears up the confusion

My bad, I did miss $y'$ there
